# Worm (Snake) Game, Pieces Growing/Moving

Tags: java, move

I'm working on programming a game similar to Snake. At the moment, I am struggling to code my move() and grow() methods. The way this game works is that the worm begins with 1 piece and grows by 1 piece with every move until it reaches 3 pieces.  After it has reached 3 pieces, it can only grow by eating an apple. Motion in this game is done by deleting the first piece and adding a new one located in the direction the worm is headed.  Move() is supposed to move the worm by one piece and grow() is supposed to grow the worm by one piece. However, when grow() is called, the worm is not supposed to grow until move() is called.  I added a private variable "growPiece" to store a piece when grow() is called and then add it when move() is called. However, I'm not getting the results I should.

```
public class Worm {

private int x;
private int y;
private Direction direction;
private List<Piece> pieces;
private Piece growPiece;

public Worm(int originalX, int originalY, Direction originalDirection) {
    this.x = originalX;
    this.y = originalY;
    this.direction = originalDirection;
    this.pieces = new ArrayList<Piece>();
    this.pieces.add(new Piece(this.x, this.y));
    this.growPiece = null;
}

public List<Piece> getPieces() {
    return this.pieces;
}

public void move() {
    if (this.direction == Direction.RIGHT) {
        this.pieces.add(new Piece(this.pieces.get(this.pieces.size() - 1).getX() + 1, this.pieces.get(this.pieces.size() - 1).getY()));
    } else if (this.direction == Direction.LEFT) {
        this.pieces.add(new Piece(this.pieces.get(this.pieces.size() - 1).getX() + 1, this.pieces.get(this.pieces.size() - 1).getY()));
    } else if (this.direction == Direction.DOWN) {
        this.pieces.add(new Piece(this.pieces.get(this.pieces.size() - 1).getX(), this.pieces.get(this.pieces.size() - 1).getY() + 1));
    } else if (this.direction == Direction.UP) {
        this.pieces.add(new Piece(this.pieces.get(this.pieces.size() - 1).getX(), this.pieces.get(this.pieces.size() - 1).getY() - 1));
    }
    if (this.growPiece != null) {
        this.pieces.add(growPiece);
        this.growPiece = null;
    }
    if (this.pieces.size() > 3 && this.growPiece == null) {
        this.pieces.remove(0);
    }
}

public void grow() {
    if (this.direction == Direction.RIGHT) {
        this.growPiece = new Piece(this.pieces.get(this.pieces.size() - 1).getX() + 2, this.pieces.get(this.pieces.size() - 1).getY());
    } else if (this.direction == Direction.LEFT) {
        this.growPiece = new Piece(this.pieces.get(this.pieces.size() - 1).getX() - 2, this.pieces.get(this.pieces.size() - 1).getY());
    } else if (this.direction == Direction.DOWN) {
        this.growPiece = new Piece(this.pieces.get(this.pieces.size() - 1).getX(), this.pieces.get(this.pieces.size() - 1).getY() + 2);
    } else if (this.direction == Direction.UP) {
        this.growPiece = new Piece(this.pieces.get(this.pieces.size() - 1).getX(), this.pieces.get(this.pieces.size() - 1).getY() - 2);
    }
}
```

I'm having trouble getting the methods to talk to each other without using parameters.

Comment: what's wrong with using parameters

Comment: Can you explain in more detail exactly what is happening? Is the grow function just not doing what it should?

Comment: Please disregard, I believe I have solved it.

Comment: Doesn't look like you have a getter/ setter for Direction? Maybe that's what you need. Once you have that all you need is to set the direction whenever there is user input. After that you'll run move() each time iteration, and run grow() instead of move whenever it runs into an apple (right?)

Comment: Please don't add "solved" into your question title, when the problem is solved. Accepting the correct answer is all you need to do (and you've done that already).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the function move(), if this.growPiece is or is not null in the beginning of the function and pieces.size > 3, the grow piece will be added and then immediately removed because either way by the time you get to that if, growPiece is null.

By that I mean, look at the two if statements at the end of move(). In the first one, if this.growPiece has been assigned, growPiece is added to the pieces ArrayList which I have to assume will have the effect you intend. After you add it you make growPiece null.

In the next if part of the conditional is that growPiece is null, which by now it always will be.

Try making that an else if and see if that works better.

Answer (score 0):

All set, I used a boolean variable to flag when to grow.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete program code for Worm Game, Exercise 49, Helsinki University's MOOC on Object Oriented Programming. 
The explanations throughout the code might seem too detailed but they are addressed to the learner, not the professional developer.
The structure of the program is not exactly like that proposed in the exercise of the course but the result is exactly the same. 
The program has the following logic:

- The worm moves automatically across the board and its speed accelerates with every eaten apple.
- The player can move the worm up, down, left and right with the arrow keys.
- When the worm is shorter than three pieces it grows automatically with every move until the length of three pieces is reached.
- If the worm eats an apple it grows by one piece with its next move.
- If the worm runs into the frame of the field or into itself, the game is over. /If a few more lines of code are added that implement a counter, we could determine after how many events of this type the game would be terminated./
- The title of the field, i.e. the title of JFrame, is used as a dashboard display that shows the current number of eaten apples. And if the worm runs into the frame of the field or into itself, it also shows the information about the respective event.

1.

```
    public enum Direction {
    LEFT, 
    RIGHT,
    DOWN,
    UP;
    }
```

2.

```
public class Piece {

private int x;
private int y;
private int width;
private int length;
private int numberOfApples;

public Piece(int x, int y, int width, int length) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.length = length;
    this.width = width;
}

public void setNumberOfApples() {
    this.numberOfApples += 1;
}

public int getNumberOfApples() {
    return this.numberOfApples;
}

public int getX() {
    return this.x;
}

public int getY() {
    return this.y;
}

public int getWidth() {
    return this.width;
}

public int getLength() {
    return this.length;
}

/*we use the following two override methods in order to check when the worm runs into itself.
This checking is done through the method "public boolean runsIntoItself(Piece piece)" in class "Worm"*/
@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    if (this.getClass() == null) {
        return false;
    }

    if (this.getClass() != object.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }

    Piece compared = (Piece) object;
    if (this.x != compared.x || this.y != compared.y
            || this.width != compared.width || this.length != compared.length) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    if (this.getClass() == null) {
        return 1;
    }
    return this.x + this.y + this.width + this.length;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "(" + this.x + ", " + this.y + ", " + this.width + ", " + this.length + ")";
  }
}
```

3.

```
public class Apple extends Piece {
public Apple(int x, int y, int width, int length) {
    super(x, y, width, length);
   }
}
```

4.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Worm extends Piece {

private int growth;
Direction direction;
private List<Piece> piecesWorm;
private JFrame frame;

public Worm(int x, int y, int width, int length, Direction originalDirection) {
    super(x, y, width, length);
    this.growth = 0;
    this.direction = originalDirection;
    this.piecesWorm = new ArrayList<Piece>();
    this.piecesWorm.add(new Piece(x, y, width, length));
    frame = new JFrame("Number of Apples: " + super.getNumberOfApples());
}

public JFrame getFrame() {
    return this.frame;
}

public Direction getDirection() {
    return this.direction;
}

public void setDirection(Direction dir) {
    this.direction = dir;
}

public int getLength() {
    return this.piecesWorm.size();
}

public List<Piece> getPieces() {
    return this.piecesWorm;
}

/*this method takes the calculated new piece from method "calculateNewPiece"
and does the following:
# moves the worm(adds an element to the head and substructs an element from the tail) 
# makes the worm grow(only adds an element to the head)
# terminates the game if the worm runs into itself*/
public void move() {
    if (this.runsIntoItself(this.calculateNewPiece()) == false) {
        if (this.piecesWorm.size() < 3) {
            this.piecesWorm.add(this.calculateNewPiece());
        } else if (this.piecesWorm.size() >= 3) {
            if (this.growth == 0) {
                this.piecesWorm.add(this.calculateNewPiece());
                this.piecesWorm.remove(0);
            } else if (this.growth == 1) {
                this.piecesWorm.add(this.calculateNewPiece());
                this.growth = 0;
            }
        }
    } else {
        this.frame.setTitle("The worm has run into itself!!! "
                + "Total Number of Apples: " + (this.getNumberOfApples()));
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
/*this method calculates the next piece of the worm according to its direction*/
public Piece calculateNewPiece() {
    // lpbm stands for "lastPieceBeforeMoving"
    Piece lpbm = null;
    Piece newPiece = null;
    if (this.piecesWorm.size() == 1) {
        lpbm = this.piecesWorm.get(0);
    } else {
        lpbm = this.piecesWorm.get(this.piecesWorm.size() - 1);
    }
    int x = lpbm.getX();
    int y = lpbm.getY();

    if (this.direction.equals(Direction.LEFT)) {
        newPiece = new Piece(x - 1 - super.getWidth(), y, super.getWidth(), super.getLength());

    } else if (this.direction.equals(Direction.RIGHT)) {
        newPiece = new Piece(x + 1 + super.getWidth(), y, super.getWidth(), super.getLength());

    } else if (this.direction.equals(Direction.DOWN)) {
        newPiece = new Piece(x, y + 1 + super.getLength(), super.getWidth(), super.getLength());

    } else if (this.direction.equals(Direction.UP)) {
        newPiece = new Piece(x, y - 1 - super.getLength(), super.getWidth(), super.getLength());
    }
    return newPiece;
}

/*this method sets the conditions that determines whether the worm will grow or not when
the method "move()" is called*/
public void grow() {
    this.growth = 1;
}

/*this method checks whether the worm runs into an apple*/
public boolean runsInto(Piece piece) {
    Piece headPieceOfWorm = this.piecesWorm.get(this.piecesWorm.size() - 1);
    if ((headPieceOfWorm.getX() + (headPieceOfWorm.getWidth())) < piece.getX()) {
        return false;
    } else if (headPieceOfWorm.getX() > (piece.getX() + piece.getWidth())) {
        return false;
    } else if ((headPieceOfWorm.getX() + (headPieceOfWorm.getWidth())) >= piece.getX()
            && (headPieceOfWorm.getX() <= (piece.getX() + piece.getWidth()))) {
        if (headPieceOfWorm.getY() + (headPieceOfWorm.getLength()) < piece.getY()
                || (headPieceOfWorm.getY() > piece.getY() + (piece.getLength()))) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

/*this method checks whether the worm runs into itself*/
public boolean runsIntoItself(Piece piece) {
    if (this.piecesWorm.contains(piece)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "(" + super.getX() + ", " + super.getY() + ", " + super.getWidth()
            + ", " + super.getLength() + ", " + this.getDirection() + ")";
   }
}
```

5.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.List;

public class AvoidOverlappingPieces {

/*this method calculates the initial position of the apple 
so that the apple is within the field and it does not overlap with the worm*/
public Apple initialApple(Worm worm, int fieldWidth, int fieldLength, int pieceWidth, int pieceLength) {
    Random random = new Random();
    Apple apple = null;
    while (true) {
        int xApple = random.nextInt(fieldWidth - (pieceWidth));
        int yApple = random.nextInt(fieldLength - (pieceLength));
        apple = new Apple(xApple, yApple, pieceWidth, pieceLength);
        if (xApple + (pieceWidth) < worm.getX()) {
            break;
        } else if (xApple > worm.getX() + pieceWidth) {
            break;
        } else if ((xApple + (pieceWidth) >= worm.getX())
                && (xApple <= worm.getX() + pieceWidth)) {
            if (yApple + (pieceLength) < worm.getY()
                    || (yApple > worm.getY() + (pieceLength))) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return apple;
}

/*this method calculates the position of the new apple, after the previous one is eaten
by the worm, so that the apple is within the field and it does not overlap with the worm*/
public Apple replaceEatenApple(Worm worm, List<Piece> piecesWorm, int fieldWidth, int fieldLength, int pieceWidth, int pieceLength) {
    Random random = new Random();
    Apple apple = null;
    while (true) {
        int xApple = random.nextInt(fieldWidth - (pieceWidth));
        int yApple = random.nextInt(fieldLength - (pieceLength));
        Apple newApple = new Apple(xApple, yApple, pieceWidth, pieceLength);
        if (this.fieldExeptWorm(newApple, piecesWorm) == false) {
            apple = newApple;
            break;
        }
    }
    return apple;
}
/*this method calculates the available space, taking account of the current    
position of worm, and it is used in the method "replaceEatenApple(...)"*/
    public boolean fieldExeptWorm(Piece piece, List<Piece> piecesWorm) {
        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < piecesWorm.size(); i++) {
        Piece wormPiece = piecesWorm.get(i);
        if ((wormPiece.getX() + (wormPiece.getWidth())) < piece.getX()) {
            counter++;
        } else if (wormPiece.getX() > (piece.getX() + piece.getWidth())) {
            counter++;
        } else if ((wormPiece.getX() + (wormPiece.getWidth())) >= piece.getX()
                && (wormPiece.getX() <= (piece.getX() + piece.getWidth()))) {
            if (wormPiece.getY() + (wormPiece.getLength()) < piece.getY()
                    || (wormPiece.getY() > piece.getY() + (piece.getLength()))) {
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
    if (counter == piecesWorm.size()) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
   }
}
```

6.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class WormGame {

private int fieldWidth;
private int fieldLength;
private int pieceWidth;
private int pieceLength;
private Worm worm;
private Apple apple;
private Random random;
/* class "AvoidOverlappingPieces" contains methods that calculate
the initial spot of the apple and its subsequent positions across the field*/
private AvoidOverlappingPieces properPieces;
protected int applesNumber;

public WormGame(int fieldWidth, int fieldLength) {
    this.fieldWidth = fieldWidth;
    this.fieldLength = fieldLength;
    this.pieceWidth = (this.fieldWidth - 10) / 10;
    this.pieceLength = (this.fieldLength - 10) / 10;
    this.worm = new Worm(0, 0, pieceWidth, pieceLength, Direction.DOWN);
    this.random = new Random();
    this.properPieces = new AvoidOverlappingPieces();
    this.apple = this.properPieces.initialApple(this.worm, this.fieldWidth, this.fieldLength, this.pieceWidth, this.pieceLength);
}

public int getfieldWidth() {
    return this.fieldWidth;
}

public int getfieldLength() {
    return this.fieldLength;
}

public Worm getWorm() {
    return this.worm;
}

public Apple getApple() {
    return this.apple;
}

/*this method accelerates the worm as it grows longer, 
through calculating smaller and smaller values for the number 
of milliseconds that are fed into "Thread.sleep(int number)",
implemented in the method "action()";*/
public int setDelay(Worm worm) {
    int delay = 1500 / worm.getLength();
    return delay;
}

/*this method takes the calculated new piece from method "calculateNewPiece" 
from class "Worm" and does the following:
# checks whether the new piece of the worm is within the confines of the field.
# if the new piece is within these confines the method "move()" from class "Worm" is called.
# if the worm bupms into an apple, the method "grow()" from class "Worm" and 
the method "replaceEatenApple(...)" from class "AvoidOverlappingPieces" are called.
# if the new piece is outside the confines of the field the game is terminated.*/
public void action() {
    int x_nextStep = this.worm.calculateNewPiece().getX();
    int y_nextStep = this.worm.calculateNewPiece().getY();
    if (x_nextStep >= 0 && (x_nextStep + this.pieceWidth) <= this.fieldWidth
            && y_nextStep >= 0 && (y_nextStep + this.pieceLength) <= this.fieldLength) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(this.setDelay(this.worm));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
        this.worm.move();
        if (this.worm.runsInto(this.apple)) {
            this.worm.setNumberOfApples();
            this.getWorm().getFrame().setTitle("Number of Apples: " + (this.worm.getNumberOfApples()));
            this.worm.grow();
            this.apple = this.properPieces.replaceEatenApple(this.worm, this.worm.getPieces(), this.fieldWidth, this.fieldLength, this.pieceWidth, this.pieceLength);
        }
    } else {
        this.getWorm().getFrame().setTitle("The worm has run into a wall!!! "
                + "Total Number of Apples: " + (this.worm.getNumberOfApples()));
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

public int getNumberOfApples() {
    return this.applesNumber;
   }
}
```

7.

```
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class KeyboardListener implements KeyListener {

private WormGame wormGame;

public KeyboardListener(WormGame wormGame) {
    this.wormGame = wormGame;
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
        this.wormGame.getWorm().setDirection(Direction.LEFT);
    } else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
        this.wormGame.getWorm().setDirection(Direction.RIGHT);
    } else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
        this.wormGame.getWorm().setDirection(Direction.DOWN);
    } else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
        this.wormGame.getWorm().setDirection(Direction.UP);
    }
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
   }
}
```

8.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class DrawingBoard extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

private WormGame wormGame;
/*"Timer" sets the speed with which the worm moves.
Since in our case the worm accelerates with every eaten apple through 
"Thread.sleep()" applied in method "action()", class "WormGame", the "Timer" here 
sets the maximum speed. 
In other words:
the initial speed (i.e. delay in the movement of the worm) is the sum of 
the value of the integer in "Timer", which is 400, plus the value of the integer in 
"Thread.sleep", which is 1500, totalling to 1900.   
So, theoretically the value in "Thread.sleep" could be reduced to nearly zero, thus 
the maximum speed of 400 milliseconds delay remains the upper speed limit. 
Of course these values could be changed as per the desire of the player.*/
Timer tm = new Timer(400, this);

public DrawingBoard(WormGame wormGame) {
    this.wormGame = wormGame;
    super.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
}
/*this method paints the initial positions of the apple and the worm*/
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    for (Piece w : this.wormGame.getWorm().getPieces()) {
        g.fill3DRect(w.getX(), w.getY(), w.getWidth(), w.getLength(), true);
    }
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillOval(this.wormGame.getApple().getX(), this.wormGame.getApple().getY(),
            this.wormGame.getApple().getWidth(), this.wormGame.getApple().getLength());
    tm.start();
}
/*this method paints the positions of the apple and the worm as they move across the board*/
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    this.wormGame.action();
    repaint();
   }
}
```

9.

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class UserInterface implements Runnable {

private JFrame frame;
private WormGame wormGame;

public UserInterface(WormGame wormGame) {
    this.wormGame = wormGame;
}

public void run() {
    frame = this.wormGame.getWorm().getFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.createCompoent(frame.getContentPane());
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

private void createCompoent(Container container) {
    DrawingBoard board = new DrawingBoard(this.wormGame);
    container.add(board);
    KeyboardListener kL = new KeyboardListener(this.wormGame);
    frame.addKeyListener(kL);
    container.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(this.wormGame.getfieldWidth(), this.wormGame.getfieldLength()));
   }
}
```

10.

```
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Run {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    WormGame game = new WormGame(510, 510);
    UserInterface ui = new UserInterface(game);
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(ui);
   }
}
```